# How to allow a Component to take a parameter that is either a FunctionComponent or a Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using Typescript and ReactJS, and I'm a noob.  I'm trying to do something that I think should be simple, but Typescript is getting in the way.

I've got two React page components defined like:

```
const HomePage: React.FunctionComponent = () => (
  // stateless component, just JSX and no logic
)


class ReceiptPage extends React.Component<IReceiptPageProps> {
  // has logic and state, defines render()
}
```

And another component that should be able to take both of these as a parameter:

```
export interface IPublicRouteWrapperProps extends IPublicRouteProps {
  component: typeof Component;   // <---- Works for ReceiptPage, but not HomePage
  layout: typeof Layout;
}

const PublicRouteWrapper: React.FunctionComponent<IPublicRouteWrapperProps> = ({
  component: Component,
  layout: Layout,
  ...rest
}) => (
  <PublicRoute
    {...rest}
    render={props => (
      <Layout>
        <Component {...props} />
      </Layout>
    )}
  />
);
```

This works when I pass in the ReceiptPage component, but not when I pass in the HomePage component:

```
    <PublicRouteWrapper
      title="blah"
      path={`${match.url}`}
      component={HomePage} // <-- error here, but works fine with ReceiptPage
      exact={true}
    />
```

The error is:

> Type 'FunctionComponent<{}>' is not assignable to type 'typeof Component'.
> Type 'FunctionComponent<{}>' provides no match for the signature 'new <P = {}, S = {}, SS = any>(props: Readonly<P>): Component<P, S, SS>'.

And that makes sense, because HomePage is not of that type.

But I can't figure out what it *should* be.  Is there a way that I can define `PublicRouteWrapper` so that either page works as a parameter?

Comment: Would something like a union of `React.Component` and `React.FunctionComponent` types be what you are looking for?

Comment: If it is a generally-accepted way of doing things, then yes, that'll work, please show me.

Comment: Would `React.ReactNode` or `JSX.Element` work? That seems to be pretty common.

Comment: @HaveSpacesuit Don't know.  I'm a noob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `React.ComponentType`, which is a union of `ComponentClass` (an interface for representing class components) and `FunctionComponent`. The type can be parameterized with the props type, but you can choose `any` to allow all components with any props. At a later moment you could increase type safety by specifying the actual type.

The `IPublicRouteWrapperProps` interface can be written as:

```
export interface IPublicRouteWrapperProps extends IPublicRouteProps {
  component: React.ComponentType<any>;   // <----  Works for both ReceiptPage & HomePage
  layout: typeof Layout;
}
```

Comment: This change makes the `<Component {...props} />` line throw a type error.  What corresponding changes are needed in the `PublicRouteWrapper` definition?

Comment: Hmm, that depends on the type of those `props`. You can parameterize `React.ComponentType` with that type, or you can first try using `React.ComponentType<any>`. The typings for routes in `react-router` are quite subtle, so it is hard to say what the solution is without a more complete example.

Comment: The `<any>` did it!  Change your answer to `component: React.ComponentType<any>;` and I'll accept it.

Comment: Good to hear! Ideally you wouldn't use `any` there, but determining the exact type would be a bit outside the scope of the question.

Comment: If it helps, the `IPublicRouteProps` extends `RouteProps`, and its component is.... haha, it's a `React.ComponentType<any>`!  So I guess this answer isn't any worse than what is already there!